# 401 on GCM requests in Node.js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to setup GCM messaging on my application backend.

The backend is running with Node.js

This is the code I'm using:

```
var apiKey = "AIz*******";
var postData = JSON.stringify({
    "notification": {
        "title": "Hello World"
    }
});

var options = {
    host: 'android.googleapis.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/gcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'key=' + apiKey,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
    }
};

var rqst = https.request(options, (response) => {
var responseBody = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        responseBody += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
        res.send(responseBody)
    });
});

rqst.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('problem with request: ${e.message}');
});

rqst.write(postData);
rqst.end();
```

But I always receive a 401 answer:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The API key I use is take from the Google developers console on

API Manager > Credentials > API key [image: Google developers console API Manager > Credentials > API key]

[image: API Manager > Dashboard]

Am I missing something?

Do you know why are my requests unauthorized?

Comment: Have you enabled this API?

Comment: that's a good point. it should be enabled, I will edit and add a screenshot of the Dashboard API section of the project. I have " Google Cloud Messaging" enabled. Should I maybe allow certain type of connections / origins on it somehow?

Comment: Since you are using NodeJS as web server, have you tried using the IP Addresses API key type instead of None?

Comment: @noogui you're right! it works with IP addresses....! Thanks! I didn't think of using it, cause I assumed it's open to any ip. Now the problem is that my app runs on Elastic Beanstalk, and if a new instance starts when there is more traffic, i can't foretell which would be the IP address. I'll try to find a solution to that. Thanks for this for now tho!! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: actually, I think EBS is keeping all the instances for one application under the same public IP address :) so should be all solved with 1 IP only. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using NodeJS as web server, use the IP Addresses API key type instead of None.